# WebBrowser shortcuts not working in Outlook add-in. WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled is true

Tags: c#, outlook, webbrowser-control, add-in, office-interop

I have an Outlook add-in. Webbrowser control is shown inside UserControl on the pane. Problem is that standard shortcuts don't work (ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl+a, tab). WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled is true. Typing in the WebBrowser inside Outlook works fine.

Similar issue like mine is described in [WebBrowser shortcuts not working in PowerPoint add-in... but WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539369/webbrowser-shortcuts-not-working-in-powerpoint-add-in-but-webbrowsershortcuts). Even same reproduce steps can be used. The solution (more workaround than solution) presented there does not fit, because modal window cannot be used in my case.

I am using VS2013, .NET4.5, Outlook2013, I was not able to spot what I am doing wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, you develop an add-in, not a standalone applicaton. The only possible scenario is to set a keybord hook. See [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsod/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in) for more information.